# How to make current_user always be not nil in Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, null, cancan

Please, give me any idea about a little problem: in my Rails 3 app I need **current_user** always **be NOT nil**. I'm using Devise and CanCan for auth system and I thinking about how to implement "**guest**" user. For roles like "admin" it works fine ( **if current_user.is? :admin**), but if user is not logged in I wish to check not **user_signed_in?**, but the same way (**if current_user.is? :guest**) for example.

I think I need to put somthing creating current_user object ib before_filters of Application_Controller, but I dont' know how to create this global thing right way.

Thanks for any answers!

Answer (score 2):

You could try it like this:

```
if current_user.try(:is?, :admin)
```

So it won't matter if current_user is `nil`

Comment: Yes, it's good way, may be I'll use it in next apps, but in current work I have already so many permission checks and I hope I'll find how to do NOT change them all with .try?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using 'CanCan' you should be adding functionality like you mentioned into you Abilities class. For example:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new
    can :manage, :all if user.is? :admin
    can :read, :all if user.is? :guest
  end
end
```

For more information take a look through the Wiki or watch the screen cast:

- https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki
- http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan